# Problems with detecting button digital state

Tags: esp8266, button, debounce, esp

I am trying to start an event after pressing and holding the *FLASH built-in Nodemcu button* for a specific time, I wrote two functions, one for debouncing and detecting the state, the other is to detect the pressing time, I'm not getting any result unless I decrease the input pressing time to less than 1s, which makes the button works as a single-push button, I think i have a problem with **debouncing** the button, I can't figure out where it is?

```
/**
* @brief debounces the button and returns the current level high or low
* 
* @return int the button state 0: low, 1: high, -1 indetermined
*/
int button_state(int btn)
{
    int const DEBOUNCE = 200;
    static int hi = DEBOUNCE;
    static int lo = 0;
    if (digitalRead(buttonPin[btn]))
    {
        if (hi < DEBOUNCE)
        {
            hi++;
        }
        if (lo > 0)
        {
            lo--;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (lo < DEBOUNCE)
        {
            lo++;
        }
        if (hi > 0)
        {
            hi--;
        }
    }

    if (hi == DEBOUNCE)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (lo == DEBOUNCE)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
/**
 * @brief Detects the button state and starts a time to calculate pressing duration 
 * 
 * @param btn input button pin
 * @param PressTime Desired pressing duration to compare to
 * @return int returns 1 when PressTime is reached
 */
int PressNHold(int btn, int PressTime)
{
    int lastButtonState = 0, Startpressed = 0, endPressed = 0, holdTime = 0,
    buttonState = button_state(btn);
    if(buttonState != -1)
    {
        if (buttonState != lastButtonState)
        {
            if (buttonState == 1)
            {
                Startpressed = millis();
            }
            else
            {
                endPressed = millis();
                holdTime = endPressed - Startpressed;
                if (holdTime >= PressTime)
                {
                    Serial.printf("Button %d pressed for %ds or more\n", btn, holdTime);
                    holdTime = 0;
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    lastButtonState = buttonState;
}
.....

void loop {

if (PressNHold(buttonPin[1], 5 * 1000) == 1)
  {
   //launch your event 
  }
```

Comment: I don’t follow your debounce routine.  It is very unorthodox.  Perhaps it would do some good to study some other existing debounce code and write something that we know works.

Comment: the debounce code looks like it should work .... it would be easier to read if the `if` statements were one-liners .... replace the `PressNHold` code to just print a timestamp at button transitions ... that may help narrow down the area of failure

Comment: Does your button have a pulldown resistor?

Answer (score 1):

turns out that it is very simple, I shouldn't put buttonPin[1] a variable for PressNHold, I had to put just1, buttonPin was used already in button_state, also, PressnHold local variables should be declared static to not get a reset after function execution.